# N+1 query where the 'n' part is not always there but I need a default value

Tags: sql

I want to skip these queries to be run for every iteration on projects:

```
SELECT  "collaborations".* FROM "collaborations"  WHERE "collaborations"."project_id" = $1 AND "collaborations"."user_id" = 2 AND "collaborations"."role" = 'Leader' LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 13]]
SELECT  "collaborations".* FROM "collaborations"  WHERE "collaborations"."project_id" = $1 AND "collaborations"."user_id" = 2 AND "collaborations"."role" = 'Member' LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 13]]
```

The hardest is that not every project has a collaboration and I need a default value for them. + I don't want to loose any project which doesn't has a collaboration.

Can be done somehow using joins?
How?

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly do you need? Try to show both an example of how the DB looks, and what you want to do. This will make it easier to help you

Comment: please add table structures and expected resultset. Dummy data will be added goodies. Use SQLfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to list projects, and yet you are selecting from the `collaborations` table. Why?

Make the select over projects, and do a left join on collaborations:

```
select
 p.*,
 c.role
from projects p
left join collaborations c 
 on 
  c.project_id = p.project_id
   and
  c.user_id = 2
   and
  c.role in ('Leader', 'Member')
where
 p.is_archived = false
```

If you only need a single row per project, you'll need to do some grouping. In that case, if you only use the collaborations table for filtering, you could just move the filter to a subquery.

Comment: Well I am listing the projects... but as walking through them I am I am currently executing those two queries. I want to skip those possible to avoid n+1

Comment: @Boti What do you mean by "avoid n+1"?

Comment: By avoid n+1 to avoid to execute the two queries N times when I am iterating over the projects.

Comment: I tried your solution and it returns 192 rows. However I have 301 projects... So I need in total 301 rows in the result

Comment: @Boti Right, you only need this one query - just use something like `"collaborations"."user_id" = 2 AND "collaborations"."role" in ('Leader', 'Member')` as the inner condition. This way, you get all the projects with no collaborations, plus those that have a given user and role.

Comment: @Boti That doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you're not adding some filters that exclude some of those projects?

Comment: I am filtering out the inactive filters.
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE (is_archived = false). Then I am iterating over them executing those two to queries for each single project.
I think that this last step could be optimized. I want to find that out how.

Comment: There are some projects which don't have any collaborations at all. And I want to include those into into the result set too.

Comment: @Boti Check the update. It sounds like using a subquery will work best for you.

Comment: I am checking it by count the rows of active_projects.
Project.active_projects.count
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE (is_archived = false)
=> 293

your query returns 200 rows. Without filtering out the archived projects it returns 205

Comment: @Boti Well, obviously, it excludes projects that have a collaboration, but not with user 2 and role leader or member. If that's not what you want, what's the purpose of those queries in the first place?

Comment: What I basically want is to know for every project the role of the current user. But every project doesn't has a collaboration record. For those I want nil or a default value.

Comment: @Boti Okay, that's a lot clearer. Check the update :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Full outer join syntax so both sides of the join are replaced for nulls in case of not matching.